# Uncaught ReferenceError at HTMLButtonElement.onclick when trying to use onclick or (click) angular 8 - 14 and Datatables,net render

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using Datatables.net 1.13.x and I'm rendering a function that will be dynamically made in an element for a hyperlink to another page.  I've been using DT for over 20 years and yet, this thing, this one little thing has me stumped.

In the .ts file I have everything done correctly and the table renders fine with the name and it's hyperlink. BUT, when I click, using onclick, I get "Uncaught ReferenceError at HTMLButtonElement.onclick" but when I click using (click), nothing happens.

Here's the snippet of code...

```
....
      scrollX: true,
      scrollY: "80%",
      autoWidth: true,
      processing: true,
      serverSide: false,
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 50,
      lengthMenu: [50, 100, 200, 250],
      data: self.vsoReps.accrRepresentatives,
      columns: [{
        "className": "dt-control",
        "orderable": false,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": ""
      }, {
        type: 'text',
        data: null,
        render: (data, type, row, meta) => {
          let repname = '';
          if (data.representativeName !== null) {
            repname = '<a class="btn btn-link" title="Click to view Details" data-id="btnrep"' + row + ' id="repname_' +
              meta.row +
              "_1" +
              '" (click)="gotoRepNmeDetails($event);">' +
              data.representativeName +
              "</a>";

            return repname;
          } else {
            return "<strong>---</strong>";
          }
        }
      }, {
        type: 'text',
        data: null,
        render: (data, type, row) => {
          if (data.vso !== null) {
            return data.vso;
          } else {
            return "<strong>---</strong>";
          }
        }
      }, {
        data: null,
        type: "text",
        render: (data, type, row, meta) => {
          let casenbr = data.relatedCases;
          let listOfCases = [];
          let ULStart =
            '<ul class="column-list" style="list-style-type: none !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;">'; // FORCED To have to use this... UGH
          let LIStart = "<li>";
          let LIEnd = "</li>";
          let ULEnd = "</ul>";
          let retVal = [];
          let finalRetVal: any;

          if (casenbr !== null || casenbr !== "") {
            if (casenbr.length === 1) {
              // SINGLE CASE
              listOfCases.push(
                '<div class="btn btn-link" id="casenbr_' +
                meta.row +
                "_1" +
                '" (click)="gotoCaseDetails($event);">' +
                data.relatedCases[0] +
                "</div>",
              );
              retVal[0] = ULStart + LIStart + listOfCases + LIEnd + ULEnd;
              finalRetVal = retVal.toString();
            } else {
              // Multiple Cases 2 Col stacked
              for (let i = 0; i < casenbr.length; i++) {
                // ignore the comma and don't include it
                if (listOfCases[i] !== ",") {
                  listOfCases[i] =
                    LIStart +
                    '<div class="btn btn-link" id="casenbr_' +
                    meta.row +
                    "_" +
                    i +
                    '" (click)="gotoCaseDetails($event);">' +
                    data.relatedCases[i] +
                    "</div>" +
                    LIEnd;
                }
                retVal[i] = listOfCases[i];
              }
              finalRetVal = ULStart + listOfCases + ULEnd;
              // console.log("Final Multi-LIs before removing commas: ", finalRetVal);
            }
            finalRetVal = finalRetVal.toString().replace(">,<", ">&nbsp;<").replace('>"",""<', '>""&nbsp;""<');
            // console.log("Final Multi-LIs after removing commas: ", finalRetVal);
            return finalRetVal;
          } else {
            return "<strong>---</strong>";
          }
        }
      }, {
.....
```

It renders nicely like so:

[image: Dev Console showing code rendering nicely]

The screen looks like this...

[image: Screen shot of fully rendered hyperlink]

Now the function...

```
  gotoCaseDetails(event: any): void {
    debugger;
    let caseid = event.target.value;
    console.log("Going to Case Details: ", caseid);
    this.router.navigate['/dashboard/mydashboard/cases/' + caseid];
  }
```

QUESTION: Why doesn't the function fire when I click on it and it's rendered properly? Furthermore, the HTML is the Template of the .ts file of the same name.

- somecomponent.html
- somecomponent.ts
- somecomponent.scss

I tried addEventListener but that's like overkill when a (click) will do nicely.

FYI: All other functions that are hard coded in other HTML templates, not through Datatables rendering capabilities, work fine. Secondly, I render  tags easily in the details section of Datatables without issue rendering mailto: hyperlinks.

Comment: please share a minimal reproducible stackblitz with the issue replicated, for debugging!

Comment: I'll do my best... give me some time please